# Prevent hiding navigation bar when scroll is set programmatically

Tags: javascript, scroll, headroom.js

I have a navigation bar which becomes hidden when the user scrolls down and is shown when the user scrolls up. Similar behavior is implemented in the [Headroom.js](https://github.com/WickyNilliams/headroom.js) library. The logic of hiding and showing is called on the `scroll` event.

I also have a large table where I prepend some rows from time to time. I want this table to keep the user's view position even when the new rows are added. This is implemented as proposed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33918803/5772120) answer.

The problem is that when I prepend some rows, scroll position changes (It is changed via setting `scrollTop` property to keep scrolling position unchanged) and the navigation bar is hidden. I want to hide the navigation bar only if scrolling is initiated by the user, not by the software.

Can I prevent firing `scroll` event when changing `scrollTop` property? How can I combine this two techniques - adaptive navigation bar and table which holds its viewport unchanged when the data is added?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no easy way of controlling the default scroll functionality. Then You can apply condition using custom flag, when to trigger scrolling event and when to prevent it.

Check this thread for further understanding. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12763950/10664244